# inconsistency when switching between timezones in python

Tags: python

I have a datetime object created like this:

```
tm = datetime.datetime.strptime('2010 Aug 04 14:15:16', '%Y %b %d %H:%M:%S')
>>> tm
datetime.datetime(2010, 8, 4, 14, 15, 16)
```

I then set the timezone like this:

```
tm.replace(tzinfo=pytz.timezone('UTC'))
>>> tm
datetime.datetime(2010, 8, 4, 14, 15, 16, tzinfo=<UTC>)
```

Eventually, I change the timezone to US/Pacific like this:

```
>>> tm = tm.astimezone(pytz.timezone('US/Pacific'))
>>> tm
datetime.datetime(2010, 8, 4, 7, 15, 16, tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'US/Pacific' PDT-1 day, 17:00:00 DST>)
```

This is correct. But if I were to go into the other direction:

```
>>> tm = tm.replace(tzinfo =pytz.timezone('US/Pacific'))
>>> tm
datetime.datetime(2010, 8, 4, 14, 15, 16, tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'US/Pacific' PST-1 day, 16:00:00 STD>)
```

As you can see, using replace() with the PST timezone incorrectly assumes it is not daylight savings time. Therefore, when I convert to UTC, it adds 8 hours instead of 7.

Why is it doing this and how do I change it so it does what I want (correctly realize DST or not)?

Comment: I've had timezone issues with Python as well...

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is why you use `.astimezone` and not `.replace` when you have a `datetime` **with** a timezone. Using `.astimezone` gives the timezone a chance to adjust for things like daylight savings. **Only** use `.replace` to give a naïve `datetime` a `tzinfo` object.